# How to detect/handle low performance devices Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I am working on a [HTML canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) app that displays graphics to the screen. The graphics aren't important for the website, they just make things look pretty.

My problem is the app needs the cpu of the device to run at a certain speed or the frame rate becomes unacceptable.

Any modern phone/laptop can easily run the app, but of course not everyone has updated tech.

At that point I'd like to drop support for the device and stop rendering the animations because it will just do more harm than good.

This idea is pretty standard on the internet. For example if you want an image background for your site, but you don't want mobile phones to load the same large image as desktops then you just use some css queries to only serve the image to desktops.

This is how we can get new features pushed out while keeping backward compatibility.

However when it comes to detecting performance this isn't as easy of a task as it sounds. There's no way to get cpu specs with Javascript, and even if I could there's no way of telling what else the user is running on their machine.

This leaves me with 2 options, either run a small performance test before I start the canvas app. Or start the app and try to run a few frames and stop it if the frame rate is too low.

The problem is both of these options are pretty sketchy because the device may just have a "speed hiccup" at the start of the app, and so I shut down the animations for nothing.

Also if a user has a device that sits right on the border of the threshold sometimes the animations will load, and sometimes they won't which would probably be confusing.

Is there any "standard" on the internet to deal with this sort of problem? Would it be best to leave a footnote at the bottom of the site window when animations are turned off?

Or is it just something you have to accept when pushing the boundaries and dealing with performance?

Comment: Not aware of any standards so I don't feel this works as an answer, but why not have multiple thresholds?  Having a borderline cutoff that displays a "You may be having issues, click here to disable..." banner, and then you can have the "oh god this phone is REALLY bad" cutoff that just disables them entirely, maybe with the opposite banner - "looks like you had issues, click here to re-enable animations".

Comment: @DanSmolinske That's actually a really good idea, I didn't think of that. Have the program make an "educated guess", and then give the user the final choice Thank you

Comment: An other solution, which is more for cases where the graphic must be there, is to lower the quality of your graphics absed on time execution. If two consecutive calls to rAF took more than 16ms, lower the size of your canvas by half and stretch it with CSS. Also, this kind of thing should obviously be implemented after a good code-optimization phase, because it's not because one has good specs that you should blew it up fully, try to keep your perf impact as low as possible at any time.

Comment: @Kaiido, yes that's a good idea, in fact I'm actually already doing that. I didn't mention it in the question for simplicity. The problem is some computers out there have cpu's made of wood and stone that deflect the path of water in order to form logic gates, and no matter how low I push the quality threshold, their vacuum tubes implode as the screen transcends time freezing into infinity.